# How to map stored procedure using ado.net enity Data model in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am writing a program which gets data from a database using an entity datamodel (database-first approach) with a stored procedure. I am a beginner to ASP.NET MVC, can anyone answer....
I bind database tables  and stored procedure also,but how can i bind stored procedure to controller method to insert data(database first approach am using)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF db-first and you want to call your stored procedure from controller's action, first of all, you should create a EF dataContext instance inside your action:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(){
   using(var ctx = new MyDbEntities()){
      ctx.MyMappedProcedure(arg1, arg2);
   }
   //todo: manipulate your data and/or return result from controller
}
```